# Extract file with 7Zlib command line into directory

Tags: c++, command-line, zip, unzip, 7zip

I would like to extract a file with [7za.exe](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) ([Link to download 7za.exe command line](http://www.7-zip.org/a/7za920.zip)).

I can extract with the commands `e` or `x`, but my files are extracted in the current file.
It is a mess, that is why I want to specify the destination directory.

I already tried this command but it won't work :

```
7za e myZipFile.zip myDestinationFolder
7za x myZipFile.zip myDestinationFolder
```

It says `No files to process`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've just find the way to extract my zipped files in another folder !
By default 7z extract files into the current folder...

This allow to extract the files in the **c:\soft folder** :

```
7z e archive.zip -oc:\soft *.cpp -r
```

The trick is that we have to attache the command `-o` directly before our destination directory ! So beware : no space between the command `-o` and our `destination directory path`.